# Tutorials on learning Adobe Bracket

Tags: adobe-brackets

hey guys I've just checked on this new Adobe Bracket code editor.
I want to know is there any book or video series On-line for learning this.
Just like sublime had??
thanks.

Comment: Not to be rude, but what's complicated about Sublime that required a video series or book? It takes like 20 minutes to figure out.

Comment: @ZekeSonxx there are video training series avabale online for free and even to buy. Eg. check envato site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bracket is an Open source software and still at it's infant stage. There is no book avalable yet but you can search for youtube for some presentations and there is a quick preview series on envato  too.
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Some resources:

- The ["Getting Started" project](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/blob/master/samples/root/Getting%20Started/index.html) that Brackets opens on first launch is a great overview of Brackets's more unique features (you can usually use the recent-project switcher dropdown to get back to it)
- ["How to Use Brackets" wiki documentation](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets) - frequently updated
- [Brackets overview/demo videos](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Videos)
- [Lynda.com intro training video](http://www.lynda.com/Brackets-tutorials/Adobe-Edge-Code-Brackets-First-Look/149704-2.html) (February 2014)
- [Tuts+ article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/deeper-in-the-brackets-editor--net-35527) (November 2013)